# How to turn a shell script to startup program?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keyboard, xinput

So I am currently using Ubuntu in my Lenovo 330 15ikb(Model 81DC) I am using a script https://github.com/anitaggu/ikbdop/ to disable my keyboard but I don't want to type the commands every time I open my laptop by cold booting.

Commands:-

```
./ikbdop.sh attach #to attach the internal keybord
./ilbdop.sh detach #to detach the internal keyboard
```

Is there a way to run the detach command every time I turn on my laptop or your can say how to turn that script to an startup application with automatic detach command?

***Note:- I am not a professional so please write in a simple language.***

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Zorin OS is off-topic here, so your question will probably be closed as off-topic, but you can try to ask on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Just to point you in the right direction, look into creating a `service` that runs on startup on Linux.

Comment: Oh OK. Your original post said Zorin OS, but if you ended up using Ubuntu, you are all good. I've also removed my off-topic flag as you are using Ubuntu. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Man I accidentally deleted the previous comment but anyways I don't get it how do I turn that script to startup program with automatic detach command.

Comment: @MineEster I added an answer explaining one possible way. Some other possible ways are in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/1438484).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [many ways to run a script at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/1438484), but here is one way using cron.

Create a script somewhere on your disk, say, `/home/you/myscript.sh`, and put the following in the script. This will be the commands that are ran every time you startup your computer, so double-check that they are correct. The first line (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) tells Ubuntu to use Bash to run this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/full/path/to/ikbdop.sh attach
/full/path/to/ilbdop.sh detach
```

Save the script where you want.
Make it executable (`chmod +x myscript.sh`).
Run `crontab -e` to edit your cronfile. Add a line to it that says `@reboot /full/path/to/script.sh` (replace the path with the location of your script, of course).